A way to (in effect, at least) make `color:inherit` take ancestor `color-scheme` into account? (i.e. make <textarea> inherit colors like <p>)
If I understand correctly, the correct behavior of color:inherit is that it climbs its ancestor chain until it finds an explicitly set color value, and uses that.
As part of a normalize.css/default.css type file, I'm wondering if there's a way to replace this rule:
button:not([disabled]), input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]) {
  color: inherit;
}

With something which "respects" the color-scheme of the nearest ancestor which has it specified.
If the <html> element has color-scheme:dark and a <div> on the page has color-scheme:light, then the text in a <p> child of that <div>, will be black, but due to the above color:inherit rule the text within a <textarea> child of that <div> will be white/light.
So, in summary, I'm looking for a way to make <textarea> inherit color in the same way that the <p> inherits color. The problem with simply removing the above rule is that browsers use color:fieldtext for textareas, color:buttontext for buttons, etc. which I don't want.

So, there's one flaw in your logic here I think. You say "The problem with simply removing the above rule is that browsers use color:fieldtext for textareas, color:buttontext for buttons, etc. which I don't want.". Yet, if you don't do this, how does it know what colour to use in light mode, and what colour to use in dark mode? You haven't defined these anywhere. The p tag is only working because it too is using a system colour

If you defined the colours that you want in light more and in dark mode higher up (e.g. on the body), e.g. using something like the new light-dark function, then I think it would inherit just fine

So, I think the problem lies here:

The problem with simply removing the above rule is that browsers use color:fieldtext for textareas, color:buttontext for buttons, etc. which I don't want.

By default, the p tag is also using a default colour provided by the browser, and I don't believe that you've overridden that if you're getting the behaviour you're describing here (otherwise your p would also behave the same as your textarea).
However, you've explicitly told the textarea to inherit its colour (which will always be from the last actual explicit colour definition, not from a system colour) --- and besides, even if it inherited the default colour from the p tag, you've stated you don't want to use the browser default colours anyways (most good CSS resets want to set the default colour explicitly anyway, in case the user has set their default browser stylesheet to have something wacky, and this seems like an especially good idea if you want to support light mode / dark mode).
So, how should it know what colour to use in dark mode vs what colour to use in light mode if you haven't defined them?
The color: inherit rule works perfectly fine if you define the colours you want to use somewhere high up, and change them along with the theme, e.g:


body {
  color: light-dark(#111, #eee);
  background-color: light-dark(#eee, #111);
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

textarea {
  color: inherit;
}
<div>
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
  <textarea>Test!</textarea>
</div>




+1 because "p tag is also using a default colour" was a helpful correction, but an important part of the question is: "which 'respects' the color-scheme of the nearest ancestor which has it specified" and IIUC this answer doesn't do that. E.g. if you visit this with your device in dark mode: https://jsbin.com/wevamudovu/edit?html,output The color:inherit will cause the color in the textarea to be incorrect. It "climbs past" the ancestor with color-scheme:light since that obviously doesn't set an explicit color value, even though it does implicitly change child textarea colors.

This is actually a super interesting problem. I'm not even sure that the p tag colour in your jsbin is correct either --- with light-dark(#222, #ccc) in a color-scheme: light div, I would expect its colour to be #222, but it's rendered as #ccc for me (Chrome 128 on Mac). For instance, check out this example: https://jsbin.com/sifuzubali/1/edit?html,output

Even weirder, the browser dev tools seem to think the colours are being applied differently to how they actually are: https://imgur.com/a/zcIPX4S There definitely could be a browser rendering bug here...

The p tags get the expected colours if you copy-and-paste the exact same colour definition onto them. But no value, or inherit, doesn't seem to work
